# Why Set the Value of a Globally Declared Variable to it's Same Value in the Window Object?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

The [code in question](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/pubsub/pubsub.js):

```
(function(window){
    ps = {},
    ps = window.ps,
    ps.subscriptions = [],
    ps.subscribe = function(name, callback){
        ps.subscriptions.push({"name": name, "callback": callback});
        return [name,callback];
    },
    ps.unsubscribe = function(args){
        for(x=0;x<ps.subscriptions.length;x++){
            if(ps.subscriptions[x].name == args[0], ps.subscriptions[x].callback == args[1])
                ps.subscriptions.splice(x, 1);
        }
    },
    ps.publish = function(name, args){
        var temp = [];
        if(ps.subscriptions.length > 0){
            for(var x=0;x<ps.subscriptions.length;x++) {
                if(ps.subscriptions[x].name == name)
                    temp.push({"fn":ps.subscriptions[x].callback});
            }
            for(x=0;x<temp.length;x++){
                temp[x].fn.apply(this,[args]);
            }
        }
    };

    console.log(window.ps);
    console.log(ps);
})(window);
```

My questions:

1. I assume that all methods / variables are being declared in the `global` scope, correct? I ask because this assumption drives the other questions I have and I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.
2. What is the point of doing `ps = window.ps` if, in the above line he's already declared `ps` in the global scope? Isn't what's being done the equivalent of `ps = ps`?
3. If the above logic mentioned in question 2 has a name or convention,
   what is it? I couldn't think of a good way to Google what I was
   seeing.

If anyone has a better way of describing the technique and wants to update my question title to make it easier to find, please feel free to do so.

Comment: That code is missing a `var` keyword at the beginning.  It would throw an error in "strict" mode.

Comment: @Pointy Okay, good. I'm not crazy then when I looked at the way the variables were being declared and started thinking "what the..."

Comment: Yes, lazy implicit globals are a bad practice and can cause all sorts of terrifically irritating bugs.

Answer (score 1):

That's bad code. A better way to do that would be:

```
(function(window){
    var ps = window.ps || {},
    ps.subscriptions = [],
    // ...

    window.ps = ps;
})(this);
```

For good measure, I'd add

```
"use strict"; // turn on "strict" mode
```

at the very beginning too.